# Six Wire Servo with Arduino

Tags: arduino, power-supply, motor, servo, pins

I have a Tamagawa 200 step servo, 6.4V. I want to test it with my Arduino Uno. My only problem is that it has 6 wires (white, red, black, green, blue and yellow) and I can not find a simple way to test it. My Question is:

How/ What do I use to test it and what are the extra wires for?

I belive it is a presison servo? If that makes sense.

Comment: Find the datasheet (or a manual) for the servo.

Comment: That isn't a servo, it's a stepper motor. You can look up its wiring with the _exact_ type number and then find 1001 Arduino tutorials for that wiring type.

Comment: If it has 6 wires the chances are that it's a unipolar stepper motor. It's easier to drive (you need only 4 transistors) than the bipolar 4-wire steppers.

Comment: Ok i think I will look for the Wire type one more time. Thanks!

Comment: No luck could not find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use Google or some other search engine and use the search string "6 wire stepper motor"

The very first link in the list that pops up is [Arduino 6 wire Stepper Motor Tutorial](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-6-wire-Stepper-Motor-Tutorial).  There are more than a million other hits with that search string.

The key words in your question that makes it clear that this is a stepper motor rather than a servo is "200 steps".  Servo motors are a continuous device rather than having discrete steps like a stepper does.

Many servo motors also have 5 or 6 wires: 2 wires for the motor and 3 or 4 wires for the potentiometer or quadrature encoder that tells the controller how far the motor has moved.  Servo motors require a completely different and much more complicated driver system than a stepper.  The advantage of servo motors over stepper motors are many: higher resolution, capable of MUCH higher power, easily scaled up or down in size.  All of those advantages are offset by the much more complicated controller required.

But you have a stepper motor.